# Reading in specific lines from an Excel spreadsheet saved as CSV file

Tags: java, excel, bufferedreader

I've got a class called TemperatureProfile, whose objects hold two attributes:

- an array of month names (type `String[]`), and
- and an array of temperatures (type `double[]`).

Now, the data for these two attributes must be read from an Excel spreadsheet saved as CSV file. The month names are in the first column, and the temperatures in the second.

I'm having trouble reading in the data from these separate columns.

```
public class TemperatureProfile {
    private double[] temperatures;
    private String[] monthNames;
    public TemperatureProfile(String filename){
      ///Read data here, and store result in monthNames and temperatures respectively.
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the excel spreadsheet a `.csv` file?  Because if not, it is a lot harder to do this.

Comment: Indeed it is! My mistake for omitting that.

Comment: If it's a `csv` file, it's just a text file. Open a reader for it, read line by line and split by the `,`.

Comment: How do I read it in separate columns?

Comment: I'd like to read in the first, and store it in monthNames, and then read in the second and store it in temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("F:\\test.csv")));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
        String[] splitrow = line.split(";");
        System.out.println(splitrow[0] + " - "+splitrow[1]);
    }
    reader.close();
}
```